# Load private key without saving local private key information

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl-certificate

maybe the title is a bit confusing, but I try to explain my problem.

My software sends some information to my server via WCF. The transport is secured with TransportWithMessageCredential and I use a certificate for the ClientCredentialType. The certificate is a .pfx file which is embedded as a Resource in the Project.

Till now I loaded the X509Certificate2 directly with the embedded certificate:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Resources.ClientCertificate);
```

All worked fine. But now a customer has a problem that the certificate couldn't be loaded. I found out, that when I call the constructor from above .NET creates a private key file under "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys". 
The customer works with terminal server and the user don't have a user profile.

**Now my main question:**

Is there a way to load the certificate without creating this private key file? I know that I could change the location to machine key set with X509KeyStorageFlags. But that is no option because the user don't have permissions to this location.

**What I have done so far:**

I exported the private key as XML with

```
File.WriteAllText(keyFile, certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
```

on the client side I created a X509Certificate2 without private key and imported the private key from XML

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
provider.FromXmlString(File.ReadAllText(keyFile));
certificate.PrivateKey = provider;
```

All worked fine but when I try to contact the WCF Server I get an error "Key does not exist."

Does someone know a solution for my problem?